# Reading multiple arrays in a text file in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read multiple arrays saved in `.txt` file. I present the data in `Test.txt` file as well as the current and expected outputs.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import ast

with open('Test.txt') as f:
    s = f.readlines()
    #print(s)
    s = ' '.join(s)
    s  = re.findall("\((\[[\w\W]*\])\)",s)
    s=ast.literal_eval(s[0])
    s=np.array(s)
    print([s])
```

The data in `Test.txt` is

```
[array([[1.7],
       [2.8],
       [3.9],
       [5.2]])]
[array([[2.1],
       [8.7],
       [6.9],
       [4.9]])]
```

The current output is

```
line 4
    [5.2]])]
          ^
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[1.7],
       [2.8],
       [3.9],
       [5.2]])]
[array([[2.1],
       [8.7],
       [6.9],
       [4.9]])]
```

Comment: `eval(' '.join(f.readlines()).replace('array', 'np.array').replace(')]', ')],'))` should do the job while not being very robust. Why not using npy files or hdf5 for that which are specifically design for such use case and avoid such AST/eval ugly inefficient tricks?

Comment: This yields ```([array([[1.7],
       [2.8],
       [3.9],
       [5.2]])],)``` which is not the expected output.

Comment: Id did not test sorry. A `replace('\n', '')` was missing. Still, it create a big array and not many one because `np.array` cannot create the expected result in one call. You need to parse each array separately and call `np.array` on each and then add each array to a list with `append`. Regarding the output, it looks like you want an array of shape (n, 1) containing object arrays of shape (m,1). Object-based array are discouraged as they are inefficiently supported (and are not really useful compared to lists here). Please clarify the output *type*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import re
import ast

s = '''
    [array([[1.7],[2.8],[3.9],
       [5.2]])]
[array([[2.1],
       [8.7],
       [6.9],
       [4.9]])]
'''

s = s.replace('\n', '')
s = s.replace(' ', '')
s = s[1:-1]
s = re.findall("\((\[.*?\])\)",s)

result= []

for i in s:
    result.append(ast.literal_eval(i))
    
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[[1.7], [2.8], [3.9], [5.2]], [[2.1], [8.7], [6.9], [4.9]]]
```